# How to retrieve live values from a website?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I am trying to retrieve the buy and sell values from the website:
https://www.zebpay.com/#chart

[image: the buy and sell price under the banner zebpay]

I tried the following code in python:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.zebpay.com/#chart')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

for item in soup.find_all(id = 'topsell'):
    print(item)
```

But I get only this result:

```
<span id="topsell"></span>
```

Whereas I can clearly see the values when I do inspect elements:

[image]

How can I solve this?

Comment: I guess that data in `topsell` populated with js calls from frontend and you need to simulate client in order to obtain it with bsoup

Comment: check out [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/) or some similar tool

Comment: Or, much better, use the Zebpay API which is intended for this: https://www.zebapi.com/api/v1/market/ticker/btc/inr

Comment: @DanielRoseman thanks a lot :)